# open local pdf file Android

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

I'm downloading a pdf file to the Downloads folder to view.  For iOS and Win32 this is easy because the `TWebBrowser` handles pdf files fine.  My problem is with Android.  Below is my code:

```
if (FileExists(LFileName))    // pdf file is there
{
 #if defined(_PLAT_IOS) || defined(_PLAT_MSWINDOWS)
  Form1->WebBrowser1->URL = "file://" + LFileName;
  Form1->WebBrowser1->Visible = true;
 #endif

 #if defined(_PLAT_ANDROID)
  Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JIntent intent = 
  TJIntent::Create();
  intent->setDataAndType(StringToJString("file://" + System::Ioutils::TPath::Combine(System::Ioutils::TPath::GetSharedDownloadsPath(), LFileName)), StringToJString(L"application/pdf"));
  intent->setAction(TJIntent::JavaClass->ACTION_VIEW);
  if (SharedActivity()->getPackageManager()->queryIntentActivities(intent, TJPackageManager::JavaClass->MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)->size() > 0) {
   SharedActivity()->startActivity(intent);
  } else {
   ShowMessage("PDF viewer not found");
  }
 #endif
}
```

When i run it on an Android it opens Adobe PDF viewer but does not open the file.

I'm guessing that i'm not passing the pdf filename properly.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**:  Ok, use of `file://` is deprecated and it looks like only way to go is via FileProvider - per [this SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed).  Miles of hard road for someone at my level.  I just want to display a pdf.

thanks,
russ

Comment: I've spend 3-4 days on this and it looks like a real nightmare.  Solutions i've seen on Android groups work up to Api 10 but fail >=10.  We really need an FMX control that displays pdf files on Android (like `TWebBrowser` will on iOS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT IT!  Dave's help [with this](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/1361-android-how-to-call-a-tjintent/) delphi question got me over the hump.  Here is my code:

```
 _di_JIntent MyIntent;
 _di_Jnet_Uri Uri;
 UnicodeString URLtest;
 URLtest = System::Ioutils::TPath::Combine(System::Ioutils::TPath::GetSharedDownloadsPath(), "sample.pdf");
 Uri = TAndroidHelper::JFileToJURI(TJFile::JavaClass->init(StringToJString(URLtest)));
 MyIntent = TJIntent::JavaClass->init(TJIntent::JavaClass->ACTION_VIEW);
 MyIntent->setData(Uri);
 MyIntent->addFlags(TJIntent::JavaClass->FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 TAndroidHelper::Activity->startActivity(MyIntent);
```

Note, i had to make sure `Secure File Sharing` is true under Project->Options->Application->Entitlement List, and i had to make sure my app [had access](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Android_Permission_Model) to the devices Storage.  Very happy day....

Also, here is that same code but with a check at the end to make sure there is an app that can actually display a pdf:

```
_di_JIntent MyIntent;
_di_Jnet_Uri Uri;
 UnicodeString URLtest;
 URLtest = System::Ioutils::TPath::Combine(System::Ioutils::TPath::GetSharedDownloadsPath(), "2009_FDA_paper.pdf");
 Uri = TAndroidHelper::JFileToJURI(TJFile::JavaClass->init(StringToJString(URLtest)));
 MyIntent = TJIntent::JavaClass->init(TJIntent::JavaClass->ACTION_VIEW);
 MyIntent->setData(Uri);
 MyIntent->addFlags(TJIntent::JavaClass->FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 //TAndroidHelper::Activity->startActivity(MyIntent);
 SharedActivity()->startActivity(MyIntent);
 if (SharedActivity()->getPackageManager()->queryIntentActivities(MyIntent, TJPackageManager::JavaClass->MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)->size() > 0) {
   SharedActivity()->startActivity(MyIntent);
 } else {
    ShowMessage("PDF viewer app not found.");
 }
```